# Remove line-height from first line

Tags: html, css, dom

I created some text which is aligned by "justify option", and I want add text leading but first line of text must be stay at x:0px y:0px.

Someone know to remove line-height from first line of

tag ?

https://jsfiddle.net/79f9rcgs/

```
body {
    margin:0;   
    padding:0;
}
.test {
    font-family:"verdana";
    font-size:25px;
    line-height:150px;
    background:yellow;
}
p::first-line {
    //line-height:0 !important; //doesn't work
}
```

[image: I want remove space marked on red]

EDIT:
Solution must be CROSS-BROWSER,

```
p:first-line { DOESNT WORK IN MOZILLA FIREROX
    line-height:100% !important;
}
```

Comment: you set a big line-height, and the text is text-align: bottom. try text-align: top

Comment: check this link i am updated  your jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mhrjnsa1/79f9rcgs/19/

Comment: on Mozilla Firefox doesn't work :(

Comment: Since you say font-size and line height can be any value, can you elaborate and clear the question, so you may get some efficient answers ... and save us time ;)

Comment: You're right, I don't precise my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also use a pseudo element with a vertical negative margin equal to the line-height to mimic a line-height:0; at first line.It will pull content upwards:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.test {
  font-family: "verdana";
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 150px;
  background: yellow;
}
p:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: -3em 0;/* 25px = 1em/font-size  150/25 = 6 . margin-top/bottom -3em = 6em */
}
```

```html
<p class="test" align="justify">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ornare odio metus, ut volutpat turpis mollis id. Aliquam sed risus congue, pulvinar erat a, fringilla ipsum. Duis posuere facilisis mauris vel fringilla. Etiam vel urna pharetra, vestibulum
  lectus eget, semper velit. Morbi eget nibh fringilla, hendrerit sem sollicitudin, aliquam enim. Quisque pulvinar felis vel lacinia cursus. Sed ullamcorper nisi nec sapien aliquet, et consequat nibh ultricies. Nullam et faucibus ante. Nam nec lectus
  varius, gravida purus et, faucibus justo.
</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/79f9rcgs/22/

Comment: It must be dynamic because line-height and font-size its various.

Comment: @LukaszML you don't say this in your question. Note i used em here which is dynamic. Now, you need to find a compromise since line-height cannot be reset only for the first-line. Dynamic you say, tell us how line-height and font-size are applied / picked up from, so we can work from there :)

Comment: So, <p> element in <div> it is placed somewhere on the page with(positon:absolute, and top:x left:y). Next when page load script add <p> element font-size and line-height.

Comment: I think that it is possible calculate how I must transform <p> in div depend on line-height and font-size but I don't know how line-height works.

Comment: @LukaszML if your script adds the line-height, so it can add at the same time the negative margin to the pseudo element since it needs to be same (but negative) value ;)

Comment: Yes I know but how calculate how much negative it must be.

Comment: negative must be line-height. if script says line-height:100px, then pseudo needs margin-top:-100px :) (

Comment: @LukaszML oups, yes of course, you only-need to remove half of the total line-height  minus the font-size so fonts stands inside the boxe

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/79f9rcgs/35/
Hmm, yes stands inside box 80/2-40 = 0 but I want to text stick to upper corner. It is possible ?

Comment: @LukaszML font-size has to be divided in halves too : https://jsfiddle.net/79f9rcgs/37/ https://jsfiddle.net/79f9rcgs/38/

Comment: Heh moment ago I figured out how to do this too :D
Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 6):

I worked a little bit in your jsfiddle you linked and I found that doing the following worked.

```
p:first-line {
    line-height:100% !important;
}
```

I hope my answer helped you with your issue! Have wonderful day.

Comment: ^^^ My browser is Mozilla Firefox

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the negative margin to shift the entire content up.

```css
body {
 margin:0; 
 padding:0;
}
.test {
 font-family:"verdana";
 font-size:25px;
 line-height:150px;
 background:yellow;
 margin-top:-60px;
}
p::first-line {
 
}
```

```html
<p class="test" align="justify">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ornare odio metus, ut volutpat turpis mollis id. Aliquam sed risus congue, pulvinar erat a, fringilla ipsum. Duis posuere facilisis mauris vel fringilla. Etiam vel urna pharetra, vestibulum lectus eget, semper velit. Morbi eget nibh fringilla, hendrerit sem sollicitudin, aliquam enim. Quisque pulvinar felis vel lacinia cursus. Sed ullamcorper nisi nec sapien aliquet, et consequat nibh ultricies. Nullam et faucibus ante. Nam nec lectus varius, gravida purus et, faucibus justo. 
</p>
```

Comment: how to count margin-top ?

Comment: @Lukasz I've just picked the appropriate one, tested first.

Comment: I creating HTML text editor so this must be calculated value because it is dynamic, line-height might be different

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap each paragraph with P tag and use first-child pseudo

check this https://jsfiddle.net/MrDahdoul/79f9rcgs/17/

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "verdana";
  font-size: 25px;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: justify;
}

#wrap p.test {
  line-height: 150px;
}

#wrap p.test:first-child {
  line-height: normal;
}




<div id="wrap">
  <p class="test">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
  </p>
  <p class="test">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
  </p>
  <p class="test">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
  </p>
  <p class="test">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: It must be like this,

<p align="justify">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ornare odio metus, ut volutpat turpis mollis id. Aliquam sed risus congue, pulvinar erat a, fringilla ipsum. Duis posuere facilisis mauris vel fringilla. Etiam vel urna pharetra, vestibulum lectus eget, semper velit. Morbi eget nibh fringilla, hendrerit sem sollicitudin, aliquam enim. Quisque pulvinar felis vel lacinia cursus. Sed ullamcorper nisi nec sapien aliquet, et consequat nibh ultricies. Nullam et faucibus ante.
</p>

no in different <p> tags

Comment: then just remove first-child pseudo and replace with first-line.
and use [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to fix default browsers different element render.
[check this](https://jsfiddle.net/MrDahdoul/0cqv5aLc/4/)